# How to extract last occurence of string, between two delimiters from multiple delimiters, using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract

```
`Something is "670px ?
am"`
```

from my input string:

```
`100000000670
? "Result was 670670px"
? Something is "670px ?
am"
? `
```

But I can't seem to get it quite right.

If I use the following regex:

```
/\n\?(.*?)\n\?\s*$/s
```

Then the extracted string is:

```
`"Result was 670670px"
? Something is "670px ?
am"`
```

And If i use:

```
/\n\?((?!\n\?)*?)\n\?\s*$/s
```

Then there is no match.
I've tried other regexes, but none seem to do the trick.

I want to extract all the characters that occur between the last two question marks that start on a newline.
There may be other question marks present in the characters to be extracted. The input string always ends in a question mark followed by a space.
What regex will extract the relevant string?

Comment: Try `/\d+px+\s*\?\s*am\b/`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oCnM1Z/1). You can remove the line break later if you want using `.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '')`.

Comment: Is it important for the extraction to omit the newline which exists in the input string?

Comment: "The input string always ends in a question mark followed by a space". Well, the input string in your question doesn't. It ends with a question mark.

Comment: That’s a mistake. The space got edited out. I’ll update.

Comment: @monkeyzeus I’m not sure I know what you mean. Newline should be included the way it is in the traction.

Comment: Your opening sentence is literally missing the new line so I'm not sure if that was a typo or you were just having formatting issues. "I am trying to extract `"670px ?am"` from my input string:"

Comment: Ah I see. No I meant anything between the last two question marks.

Comment: What rule dictates the existence of double-quotes? Do newlines cause double-quoted text or does the presence of a question mark cause it?

Comment: Double quotes maybe entirely missing or present later after the question mark. I’ve updated the question to indicate this.

Comment: So if `am"` was `? am"` instead then it should be captured or no?

Comment: Yes should be captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to extract the last string that occurs between two question marks which start on a newline. There may be other question marks in the middle but I want to ignore those. The input string always ends in a question mark followed by a space.

```js
const input = `100000000670
? "Result was 670670px"
? "670px ?
am"
? `;

const regex = /\n\?((?:[^\n]|\n(?!\?))*\n)\? $/;

const match = input.match(regex);

console.log(match[1]);
```

If you want to exclude the leading space and trailing newline just use `trim()` or trivially adjust the regex. I am just following the letter of the quote I included above, and interpreting "last string" as all characters between the question marks.

Further explanation on request.

Comment: Or `/(?<=\n\?)(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\?))*\n(?=\? $)/` with lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

To match the last string that occurs between two question marks which start on a newline:

```
\n\?[^\S\n]*(.*(?:\n(?!\?).*)*)\n[^\S\n]*\?[^\S\n]*$
```

- `\n\?` Match a newline and `?`
- `[^\S\n]*` Match optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\?).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `?`
- `)` Close group
- `\n[^\S\n]*\?[^\S\n]*` Match a newline and a `?` between optional spaces
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvBtdH/1)

```js
const regex = /\n\?[^\S\n]*(.*(?:\n(?!\?).*)*)\n[^\S\n]*\?[^\S\n]*$/;
const s = `100000000670
? "Result was 670670px"
? Something is "670px ?
am"
? `;

const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```regex
"[^"]+"(?=\s+\? $(?![\r\n]))
```

- `"[^"]+"` - get double-quoted content
- `(?=\s+\? $(?![\r\n]))` - ahead of me **must** be the question mark + space which terminates the string

  - JS does not support the "end of string" meta-character [`\Z`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) so we emulate it with `$(?![\r\n])` which translates to "no more line breaks after the end of the line"

https://regex101.com/r/lzd2gY/1/

Comment: The double quotes may not be present. The string in between two question marks could be anything. I’ll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy might be to *split* the string based on the delimiters, creating an array.  Then, pop the last element off of the array.  (Or maybe the next-to-last.)

An advantage of such logic, if it applies here, would be that it is fairly *obvious* what is happening.  "Regex spaghetti-code" is a thing to be avoided whenever possible.